# How can I populate a select field in my form on render when the options are loaded by tom-select?

Tags: javascript, session-variables, ruby-on-rails-7, tom-select

I have a form that, upon submit, will store its values in a session variable before redirecting to the same form, in order to repopulate it again with the same values. This works fine for the input fields, but my select fields have their options dynamically populated by tom-select (via stimulus controller), meaning when the form is rendered, the select fields don't have options matching the value I'm trying to select, so no value gets selected. I'm trying to figure out a way around this, but so far I'm stumped. I need to somehow select the correct value after the page is rendered. I imagine I can use javascript for this, but I'm not sure the most elegant way to go about it.

So far I've tried updating it using javascript inside the html itself, making use of the tom-select api to add the value I want (api here: https://tom-select.js.org/docs/api/)
That looked something like this:

```
<%= form.select :color, [], {}, { placeholder: "black", class: "form-select", data: { controller: 'ts--select'} } do %>
    <% if session[:form_values].present? && session[:form_values]["color"].present? %>
        <script>
            let control = document.querySelector('#item_color').tomselect; 
            control.addItem('<%= session[:form_values]["color"] %>');
        </script>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But this didn't work, I'm guessing because it's still rendering before tom-select can do its thing.

Any insight on this would be excellent.

Comment: I figured out the answer but I guess I don't have enough clout to post it. Anyway, I just added a `tomselect.on("load", handler)` event to my stimulus controller that autoselects the value from the session variable if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to pre-select the options that were selected before the submit (and repost).

In this case, the best way to do it is, in my opinion, to initialize the options AND the selected options in JavaScript like this:

```
new TomSelect("#person", {
         placeholder: "Pick or search a person",
         valueField: 'id',
         searchField: ['firstname', 'lastname'],
         options: <?=json_encode($allPerson)?>,
         items: '<?=$person?->getId()?>', //preselected
...
```

This piece of code preselects ONE person and adds it to the ITEMS array (which is the array of Tom Select already selected options). In your case, you will have to loop over the session, in a way similar to this:

```
items: '<?=json_encode($_SESSION['selectedPersonIds']);?>',
```